# Ubuntu automatically changes \ to <

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chromebook

I am currently running ubuntu on a chromebook and every time I type a \ it automatically changes to a <. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: It doesn't "change" it, it is merely using a keyboard mapping which isn't the one for your keyboard. There is likely a way to switch keyboard layouts in the user settings, usually near language/country settings. You'll likely find some variants of your current layout.

Comment: @xenoid Thank you, I found the problem was I was using an American keyboard setting instead of a UK keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my settings said I was using an American keyboard but I am using an English keyboard in real life so I needed to change the keyboard settings.

In order to do this go into:

- system settings

  - keyboard

    - text entry

then choose the plus button in the bottom left corner to add a keyboard and the minus sign to remove a keyboard. These instructions are for Gnome in Ubuntu 16.04 but might be similar for other desktop environments and versions.

Comment: These instructions work for Gnome